# How to exclude base directory from phing/ant FileSet

Tags: ant, phing, fileset, build-tools

I have a phing build target that I want to run on each directory directly under my project base. I'm using a foreach task with a fileset to run the target on each directory. The problem I'm having is that the base directory is included, with a filename of "".

Here's an example of the directory structure:

```
One
Two
build.xml
```

Here's a simple build file to test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="Test" default="test">

    <target name="test">
        <foreach param="filename" absparam="absfilename" target="echo-file">
            <fileset dir="${project.basedir}">
                <include name="*" />
                <exclude name="*.*" />
            </fileset>
        </foreach>
    </target>

    <target name="echo-file">
        <echo message="filename: ${filename}" />
        <echo message="absfilename: ${absfilename}" />
    </target>

</project>
```

And here's the results of the build (note the first entry with empty filename):

```
Buildfile: /Users/dmertl/test/build.xml

Test > test:

  [foreach] Calling Buildfile '/Users/dmertl/test/build.xml' with target 'echo-file'

Test > echo-file:

     [echo] filename: 
     [echo] absfilename: /Users/dmertl/test/
  [foreach] Calling Buildfile '/Users/dmertl/test/build.xml' with target 'echo-file'

Test > echo-file:

     [echo] filename: One
     [echo] absfilename: /Users/dmertl/test/One
  [foreach] Calling Buildfile '/Users/dmertl/test/build.xml' with target 'echo-file'

Test > echo-file:

     [echo] filename: Two
     [echo] absfilename: /Users/dmertl/test/Two
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I didn't figure this out the first time around, but here's the solution:

```
<foreach param="filename" absparam="absfilename" target="echo-file">
    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}">
        <include name="*" />
        <exclude name="/" />
        <exclude name="*.*" />
    </fileset>
</foreach>
```

Excluding "/" in the fileset removes the root directory.